# No sé por qué me aparece un none cuando se termina de ejecutar un metodo

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

estoy haciendo una calculadora poligonal y en un metodo al que llamé get_picture() se le pide que genere la forma del rectangulo/cuadrado con "*". Supongamos que el rectangulo tiene 10 de ancho y 3 de alto seria algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien pero es que automaticamente despues de que se imprime la ultima linea de "*" aparece un None y no sé a que se debe ni como sacarlo. Si alguien del foro me pudiera dar una mano con este problema diciendome a que se debe o como hacer para que no aparezca ese None se lo agradeceria. Adjunto el codigo:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def get_picture(self):
        width = self.width
        height = self.height
        if self.height <= 50 and self.width <= 50:
            if self.__class__.__name__ == "Square":
                print(f'{self.__class__.__name__}(side={width})')
            else:
                print(f'{self.__class__.__name__}(width={width}, height={height})')
            for i in range(height):
                for j in range(width):
                    print('*', end='')
                print(end='\n')
        else:
            print("Too big for picture.")

rect = Rectangle(10, 3)
print(rect.get_picture())
```

PD: Creo que el problema está en `print(rect.get_picture())` ya que si solo llamo al metodo de la siguiente manera `rect.get_picture()` se ilustra el grafico pero ya deja de aparecer el None. Entonces creo que no deberia poner `print("*", end='')` en el metodo get_picture pero tampoco return porque no fucionaría, cortaría el ciclo. En fin cualquier sugerencia la escucho.

Muchas gracias

Comment: En Python, toda función, devuelve None (excepto que se ejecute una linea de código con un return en el cual se diga explicitamente que debe devolver la función). Lo que haces en esa linea es imprimir en pantalla lo que devolvió el método rect.get_picture.

Comment: Puedes, en lugar de usar una función normal, crear una [función generadora](https://ellibrodepython.com/yield-python) que vaya generando cada nuevo caracter, juntar el resultado usando el método de cadena [join](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) e imprimir el resultado obtenido ;)

Answer (score 2):

Lorenzo. Esto se debe a que todas las funciones retornan un None

```
def get_picture(self):
    width = self.width
    height = self.height
    if self.height <= 50 and self.width <= 50:
        if self.__class__.__name__ == "Square":
            print(f'{self.__class__.__name__}(side={width})')
        else:
            print(f'{self.__class__.__name__}(width={width}, height={height})')
        for i in range(height):
            for j in range(width):
                print('*', end='')
            print(end='\n')
    else:
        print("Too big for picture.")
    # aqui debe agregar un return
```

Answer (score 1):

Al generar tu función puedes hacerla de dos maneras:

1. La función imprime directamente en pantalla los datos que sea neccesario, con lo que la llamada sería `rect.get_picture()`.
2. En la función almacenas los datos y los devuelves, así podrás trabajar con esos datos (imprimirlos, comparaciones,...).

   En tu caso quieres dos valores, el tipo y el dibujo. Puedes devolver una tupla

```
        return tipo, dibujo

rect = Rectangle(10, 3)
mi_tipo, mi_dibujo  = rect.get_picture()
print(mi_tipo)
print(mi_dibujo)
```

Como estás con un objeto también puedes crear dos atributos, `self.tipo` y `self.dibujo`

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.tipo = ''
        self.dibujo = ''

    def get_picture(self):
        if self.height <= 50 and self.width <= 50:
            res = f'{self.__class__.__name__}(side={self.width})'
            self.tipo = res + '\n' if self.__class__.__name__ == 'Square' else f', height={self.height})\n'

        #dibujo = [ ''.join('*' for j in range(self.width) ) for i in range(self.height)]
        dibujo = ('*' * self.width for i in range(self.height))
        self.dibujo = '\n'.join(dibujo)


rect = Rectangle(10, 3)
rect.get_picture()
print(rect.tipo)
print(rect.dibujo)
```

Comment: Yo modificaría esta linea `dibujo = [ ''.join('*' for j in range(self.width) ) for i in range(self.height)]` a `dibujo = ('*' * self.width for i in range(self.height))`. Como podrás ver, hice que en lugar de comprensión de listas se use de generador y multiplico la cadena para ahorrarme código.

Comment: Editado. Gracias @DanteS.

Comment: Un placer Tomy c:

Answer (score -1):

La tu clase de por si hace los prints correspondientes. Al llamar al método `get_picture` se imprime por pantalla todo lo deseado y luego se termina. Este método (como cualquier método o función de python) devuelve siempre un valor, como no está especificado este es `None`. Al llamar print sobre el método imprimirá ese `None`.
La solución es sacar el último print y dejar solo:

`rect.get_picture()`

en la última línea